# How to implement two-way binding using DynamicComponent?

Tags: c#, blazor

How do we implement two-way binding using the `DynamicComponent` razor component?

I cannot see anything in the documentation for this.

Comment: There's a reason why there's no documentation.  You can't.

Comment: You’d think that would be in the documentation seen as it’s a big part of blazor.